# Как сделать так, чтобы текст был рядом справа вместе с левым текстом

Tags: html, css, работа-с-текстом

Я хочу, чтобы текст был таким же как показано на 1 картинке. Но почему-то если использовать float (как я это сделал на 1 картине ) то почему-то текст исчезает. Если что, на 2 картине белый фон это фото и я на это фото поднял текст. Я хотел чтобы сзади этого текста был белый фон, но лучше чем просто ставить фото я не придумал.[image: 1 картина][image: 2 картина]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #010000;
  background: #77DDE7 url("images/fon.jpg") repeat-x 0 0;
  min-width: 960px;
}

.shell {
  margin: 10 auto;
  width: 1500px auto;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.header {
  background: url(images/header.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px 12px 0px 0px;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

#logo a {
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

#navigation {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

#navigation ul li a {
  color: #77777b;
  padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li.active a {
  color: #2497e0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.niz_logo {
  color: black;
  font-size: 85px;
  margin: 20px
}

.podcluchit {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#levo {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;
  float: left;
  width: 43%;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.levo {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  line-height: 30px
}

#pravo {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
  width: 46%;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.pravo {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  line-height: 30px
}

#levo2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
  width: 43%;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.levo2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  line-height: 30px
}

#pravo2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0px 10px 170px 0px;
  width: 46%;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  float: right
}

.pravo2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -1500px 0px 70px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercases
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#fon2 img {
  max-width: 100.8%;
  height: 1500px;
  padding: 120px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: inherit
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Главная</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/images/mini.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header" />
  <div class="shell" />
  <h1 id="logo"><a href="#">HaID</a></h1>
  <div class="pravo">
    <nav id="navigation">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ставки дохода</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Требования </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Партнёры</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Музыка</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <br>
  <center class="niz_logo">
    <b>Партнёрская программа HaID</b>
  </center>
  <center>
    <b><a href="#" class="podcluchit"> Подключиться </a></b>
  </center>
  <div id="levo">
    <h3>Каждый важен</h3>
    <div class="levo">HaID — единственная медиасеть, которая предоставляет выгодные условия работы даже начинающим авторам YouTube-каналов.<br> Теперь претендовать на высокую ставку дохода может каждый, кто систематически выполняет рекомендации по развитию канала.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="pravo">
    <h3>Персональное внимание!</h3>
    <div class="pravo">В других сетях только топовые видеоблогеры получают качественную поддержку и высокую ставку дохода.<br> А в HaID индивидуальная поддержка и повышенная ставка дохода доступна всем, кто работает над каналом.<br> Вне зависимости от числа подписчиков
      на канале.</div>
  </div><br>
  <div id="fon2"> <img src="css/images/fon2.jpg" alt=""> </div>
  <div class="text"> <span><center><h2>Крутые ставки дохода авторским каналам!</h2></center></span>
    <div id="levo2">
      <h4>75% Доступна всем партнёрам</h4>
      <div class="levo2">Достаточно просто работать над каналом. И делать это не по принципу «и так сойдёт». Вы сможете претендовать на повышение ставки дохода канала, если канал подключен больше 1 месяца при этом выполняет 2 из следующих условий:<br>
        <li>A. На канале регулярно размещаются качественные видео (не менее 2 видео в неделю)</li>
        <li>B. В течение последнего месяца просмотров больше 500.000</li>
        <li>C. В течение последнего месяца доход больше $300</li>
        Если вы всё это сделали, ваша ставка может быть повышена до 75%. Напишите нам!<br></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pravo2">
      <h4>80% Всем, кто всерьёз работает на YouTube</h4>
      <div class="pravo2">Если вы всерьёз нацелены на заработок на YouTube, есть ещё несколько шагов, выполняя которые вы получите ставку 80%. Вы сможете претендовать на ставку дохода 80%, если канал подключен больше 3 месяцев и при этом выполняет хотя бы одно из следующих
        условий:<br>
        <li>A. В течение последнего месяца просмотров более 2 000 000</li>
        <li>B. В течение последнего месяца доход больше $1000</li>
      </div>
    </div>
    

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: используйте [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) или [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю вы этого хотели добиться. С HTML вам нужно ещё много тренироваться. Как можно вообще теги "li" использовать без "ul" или "ol".
В общем наверстал вам нормально html и css. Оставил только блоки, которыми вы интересовались, остальное только мешало.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #010000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 40px;
}
.text {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px;
}
.item-row {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="item-row">
    <h3>Каждый важен</h3>
    <p>HaID — единственная медиасеть, которая предоставляет выгодные условия работы даже начинающим авторам YouTube-каналов.</p>
    <p>Теперь претендовать на высокую ставку дохода может каждый, кто систематически выполняет рекомендации по развитию канала.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <h3>Персональное внимание!</h3>
    <p>В других сетях только топовые видеоблогеры получают качественную поддержку и высокую ставку дохода.</p>
    <p>А в HaID индивидуальная поддержка и повышенная ставка дохода доступна всем, кто работает над каналом.</p>
    <p>Вне зависимости от числа подписчиков
      на канале.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Крутые ставки дохода авторским каналам!</h2>
<div class="text">
  <div class="item-row">
    <h4>75% Доступна всем партнёрам</h4>
    <p>Достаточно просто работать над каналом. И делать это не по принципу «и так сойдёт». Вы сможете претендовать на повышение ставки дохода канала, если канал подключен больше 1 месяца при этом выполняет 2 из следующих условий:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A. На канале регулярно размещаются качественные видео (не менее 2 видео в неделю)</li>
      <li>B. В течение последнего месяца просмотров больше 500.000</li>
      <li>C. В течение последнего месяца доход больше $300</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Если вы всё это сделали, ваша ставка может быть повышена до 75%. Напишите нам!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <h4>80% Всем, кто всерьёз работает на YouTube</h4>
    <p>Если вы всерьёз нацелены на заработок на YouTube, есть ещё несколько шагов, выполняя которые вы получите ставку 80%. Вы сможете претендовать на ставку дохода 80%, если канал подключен больше 3 месяцев и при этом выполняет хотя бы одно из следующих условий:
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>A. В течение последнего месяца просмотров более 2 000 000</li>
      <li>B. В течение последнего месяца доход больше $1000</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```